# Resetting/Deleting/Forgetting variables in Mathematica Notebooks

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I am computing some formulae in a notebook. Suppose I define a function

```
Myf[x_] := Sin[c*x] + Tanh[x/c]*Exp[-x]
```

and then compute

```
Integrate[Myf[y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

Now, just to do some sanity check, I define `c` as

```
c = 1
```

and evaluate `Integrate[Myf[y], {y, -1, 1}]` to get

```
1/E - E + 2 ArcCot[1/E] - 2 ArcCot[E]
```

Now, even if I delete the `c = 1` line, `Integrate[Myf[y], {y, -1, 1}]` still evaluates to

```
1/E - E + 2 ArcCot[1/E] - 2 ArcCot[E]
```

instead of the unsubstituted

```
(1/(-2 + c))E^(-1 - 2/
  c) (c E^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - c/2, 2 - c/2, -E^(-2/c)] - 
   E^(2/c) (c E^(2/c)
        Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - c/2, 
        2 - c/2, -E^(2/c)] + (-2 + 
         c) (E^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(c/2), 1 - c/2, -E^(-2/c)] - 
         Hypergeometric2F1[1, -(c/2), 1 - c/2, -E^(2/c)])))
```

1. How do I delete/forget the value of `c` for the notebook once I defined it.
2. What is the best way to deal with these situations. I suppose people use `Substitute` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `x=.` or [`Clear[x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html) clears `x`.

Answer (score 0):

`Quit[]`

This function quit the Kernel. It clears all the variables and stuff it could have stored after opening the notebook.

You can also try:

> ClearAll["Global`*"]